# How can I make ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter skip "" text?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView which contains a text field that is populated using a SimpleCursorAdapter. In my database, the field is allowed to be null (a desired effect), however, if the value is null, rather then having the TextView be blank (as populated by the SimpleCursorAdapter), I want it to contain some default value, say "-------". How can I acheive this effect?

It can either be done by the way I run my SQLite query, or by some method telling the textView to ignore "", and show its android:text value or something like that. Whichever method is recommended, I can't figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ifnull` in your SQL SELECT statement as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176517/how-to-write-sqlite-select-statement-for-null-records). Something like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(title, "------") FROM books;
```

or if you need the column name:

```
SELECT IFNULL(title, "------") AS title FROM books;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any special property that you can set on the TextView to show a specific value if `setText("")` is called. There is android:hint but I'm sure that goes out the window when `setText()` is called, even if it is blank, and the views are recycled so that probably wouldn't work anyway.

So you should either return the "-----" in the sql query when the value is null or use a [SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) to set the "-----" when the value is blank. Building it into the sql query should be easiest.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. How would I go about adding it to the sql query?